# Dynamically creating an association in Active Record (RoR / Ruby)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am importing seed data into my app from a CSV and I am building a generic class with methods to build my models and create associations. I have been able to take a relationship name such as `'category'` and string interpolate in a `'send'` call.. ie

`object.send("#{relationship}=", other_obj)`.

This works fine for a has_one / belongs_to relationship. Ie.

`Item.category= 'Books'`

I want to use a similar approach to for `has_many / belongs to many`, such an object that has many categories. I have tried

```
 object.send("#{relationship_plural} <<", 'Books')
```

and I am getting a missing method error for categories <<.

Any ideas ??

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer. That gives a undefined method error

Comment: @BradWerth Yes. And to be even clearer, I am trying to create the relationship between 2 objects. So Brand.find(100).send('categories <<', 'Category.last) does not work

Answer (score 0):

`object.send(relationship_plural) << Book.first`

Comment: Thanks.. Not sure why I was string interpolating. :)

Comment: Note that the Book being shoveled into the relationship isn't supposed to be a string as AR will throw an error message. It should also be an AR object

Comment: That benchmark you are referring to is from the year 2008 ! It is no longer accurate. When you run the same benchmark today, `send` is about 10 % faster. Also, that benchmark reused the method object. Instanciating it on the spot is about five times slower than using send.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by more secure? Private methods are still exposed using the second approach...

Comment: If you just ran those benchmarks, can you share them in a gist? I was meaning to do it in the morning myself...

Comment: OK, I can see that using `send` in combination with user input might lead to runtime exceptions or to methods being invoked in a harmful way. E.g. if the CSV contained a relationship name `"delete_all"`. (Using `method` in this case would still not be any more secure, though.)

Comment: @BradWerth You can copy and paste the code from the blog into irb. No further setup required. Find it here: http://blog.khd.me/ruby/ruby-dynamic-method-calling/